# parse geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground Swift sample

Tags: ios, parse-platform, geolocation

Found multiple posts on this, but still can't quite piece it together.

I'm using Parse to retrieve the user's current location.  Documentation makes it seem very easy, but several things appear to be missing.  https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#geopoints-getting-the-user-39-s-current-location

First, my code:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("Get GPS")
    PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground { (geoPoint, error ) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            print("Got geoPoint") //Never reaches this
            print(geoPoint)
        } else {
            print(error ) //No error either
        }
    }
```

- I've updated the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in my info.plist
- Tried simulator and two real devices.
- Added CLLocationManagerDelegate

I'm trying to avoid making this more complex than it needs to be.

I've also experimented with CLLocationManager samples and it doesn't seem to be working either.

I'm using most recent versions of everything... started with Parse yesterday!

I've never been challenged for authorization to use my location.  Tried that with CLLocationManager examples!

Would greatly appreciate some guidance / support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right about missing a few things before you can handle the location update from Parse.

First, add a location manager property to your class.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

Set its delegate and use it to request authorization from the user:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    print("Get GPS")
    PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground { (geoPoint, error ) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            print("Got geoPoint") //Never reaches this
            print(geoPoint)
        } else {
            print(error ) //No error either
        }
    }
}
```

In your Info.plist, you need to add a key `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and give it a string value for a message to the user during the authorization request.

The authorization request and the location update should work after the above changes.

Comment: how can one update the location, `geoPoint` retrieved from `geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground `? In other words, if the user open the app and this method gets called, then the user moves to a new location, how can one set the geoPoint to the new location?